# Using the same one dimensional array as the input of first order bessel function in python and matlab,why do I have different results?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, scipy

I'm translating code from Matlab to Python. While using the same one dimensional array as the input of first order Bessel function in Python and Matlab, why do I have different results?

Assuming `T` is the array which I input, in Matlab it's `besselj(1,T)` and in Python it's `scipy.special.jv(1,T)`.

Here's my code.

```py
wave0=5000
pixelscale=4e-4
abe = np.zeros((6,1))
psfsize=4191
diam = 2
centr = 0

temx = np.linspace(-1 * pixelscale * math.floor(psfsize/2), 
pixelscale * math.floor(psfsize/2),psfsize)
[meshtheta,meshphi] = np.meshgrid(temx,np.transpose(temx))
R_pup = np.sqrt(meshphi**2 + meshtheta**2)
teltheta = (R_pup) * np.pi * diam * (wave0 * 1e-10) / 206265

while teltheta.any() == 0:
    teltheta=1e-9

T=teltheta

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(jv(1,T),cmap='hot')
plt.show()
```

Thus I got the image matrix of Bessel function (1st order) in Python. Later I use the image matrix in Python to reduce the result in Matlab and I got result as below:

[image]

Comment: Please read [mre], then [edit] your question accordingly. If we can’t reproduce your results we can’t tell you what is going on.

Comment: Why don't you post the Matlab script, too?

Comment: I compared `besselj(1,T)` and `scipy.special.jv(1,T)` for various random values of `T`, and they both produce the same results. So, if you want us to help you with the differences you are seeing, you must show us a [mre] in both Python and MATLAB, as well as the output for both. Note that your Python code is missing the import statements, which makes it impossible to know exactly which functions are being called.

Comment: What is `while teltheta.any() == 0: teltheta=1e-9` supposed to do? I bet it doesn't do what you think it does! As long as `teltheta` has a non-zero value, `teltheta.any()` is `True`, which is not equal to 0, and so the assignment is never applied. But if it were applied, then `teltheta` would stop being a matrix, and become the scalar value `1e-9`, which i'm pretty sure is not what you intend.

Comment: thank you so much for your commenting!! The question has been solved!